# Split Crystal Graph series data

Tags: graph, crystal-reports

Morning,
I have a chart which I have flipped to be vertical.
There are a lot of data groups on the x axis making it impossible to fit on a page.

Any one know how to split the graph (a-m then m-z)

Many thanks.

Comment: Split the input to the graph as `a-m` and then `m-z` and then you have 2 graphs

Comment: I understand what you mean, but not sure how it do it....

Comment: OK, I have created two groups. group one supresses n to z and group two supress a - m.

how do I now create a chart for each group?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

Take 2 detail sections and in a sub report in each detail section.

One sub reports should fetch `a-m` data and other should fetch `m-z` data and place a graph in each sub report.